# Python subprocess returncode takes on different values

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm running a python script demo.py which is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError

try:
    process = Popen(["/root/script.sh"], stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
    process_out, process_err = process.communicate()
    return_code = process.returncode
    if process_out:
        print "output:", process_out
    if process_err:
        print "error:", process_err
    print "return code:", return_code
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print "CalledProcessError:", e
except Exception, fault:
    print "fault:", fault
```

script.sh is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /root/
mkdir foo
cd foo
cat << EOF > bar.txt
random text
EOF
```

The directory foo already exists. Hence, script.sh should fail and it does. demo.py correctly catches the error in process_err and prints it:

> error: mkdir: cannot create directory `foo': File exists

**But the value of return_code is still 0** (which indicates successful run).

If my script.sh is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /root/
mkdir foo
```

process_err prints the same error message **but now the value of return_code is 1.**

Where is the problem?

Please also suggest scenarios in which process.returncode takes on values other than 0 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem with Python, but with your Bash script that is continuing execution after `mkdir`. This is how Bash works by default, you have to tell it to exit when it encounters an error.

Use:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
```

Or, if you can't change the Bash script and you can only change the Python code:

```
process = Popen(['bash', '-e', '/root/script.sh'], stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
```

From `help set`:

> `-e` Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please also elaborate on the cases in which the returncode takes on values other than 0 and 1?

Comment: @Waltz: the exit status depends mainly on the program. For example, [ssh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) can exit with status 255, [patch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) can exit with statu 2, and so on. There are cases where a non-zero exit status does not mean than an error occurred. The exact meaning of an exit status depends on the program that produced it